# How to build elasticsearch terms query in java？

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How to use elasticsearch terms query in Java in order to achieve the following：

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/tweets/_search -d '{
  "query" : {
    "terms" : {
      "user" : {
        "index" : "users",
        "type" : "user",
        "id" : "2",
        "path" : "followers"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: You might want to add the java tag if you are interested in java answers. Also, please provide a bit more details about what you are trying to do and in which way it doesn't work as you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this in ES 2.3:

```
TermsLookupQueryBuilder terms = QueryBuilders.termsLookupQuery("user")
    .lookupIndex("users")
    .lookupType("user")
    .lookupId("2")
    .lookupPath("followers");

client.prepareSearch("tweets")
    .setQuery(terms)
    .execute().actionGet();
```

In ES 5, you'll be able to do it like this:

```
TermsLookup termsLookup = new TermsLookup("users", "user", "2", "followers");
TermsQueryBuilder terms = QueryBuilders.termsLookupQuery("user", termsLookup);

client.prepareSearch("tweets")
    .setQuery(terms)
    .execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I am using Elasticsearch 2.3.3, there are 5 parameters: TermsLookup termsLookup = new TermsLookup(index, type, id, routing, path, queryParseContext),what path and queryParseContext should be in this case？

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605442/how-to-use-elasticsearch-has-child-query-in-java  I need your help.

Comment: I tried,it does not work.  Api  changes :https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/breaking_50_java_api_changes.html

Comment: I've modified my answer, please check it again.

Comment: can you help me solve this problem?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948461/how-to-use-inner-hits-to-add-highlight-in-has-child-search-in-es-2-3-3 @Val

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after a hard way:

```
TermsLookupQueryBuilder tlqb = QueryBuilders
             .termsLookupQuery("user")
             .lookupIndex("users")
             .lookupType("user")
             .lookupId("2")
             .lookupPath("followers");
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: No worries, glad you figured it out!