# How to use elasticsearch has child query in Java?

Tags: elasticsearch

How to use elasticsearch has child query in Java in order to achieve the following：

```
{
      "query": {
        "has_child": {
          "type": "instance",
          "query": {
            "has_child": {
              "type": "instance_permission",
              "query": {
                "terms": {
                  "uuid": {
                    "index": "user",
                    "type": "user",
                    "id": "5",
                    "path": "uuids"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I have tried:

```
TermsLookup termsLookup = new TermsLookup("user", "user", "5", null, "uuids", null);
QueryBuilder qbquery = QueryBuilders.termQuery("uuid", termsLookup);
HasChildQueryBuilder bookNameQuery = QueryBuilders
                    .hasChildQuery("instance", QueryBuilders
                    .hasChildQuery("instance_permission", qbquery));
```

but return error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer:

```
TermsLookupQueryBuilder terms = QueryBuilders
                    .termsLookupQuery("uuid")
                    .lookupIndex("user")
                    .lookupType("user")
                    .lookupId("5")
                    .lookupPath("uuids");

HasChildQueryBuilder   hQuery = QueryBuilders
                       .hasChildQuery("instance", QueryBuilders
                       .hasChildQuery("instance_permission", terms));

        System.out.println("Exectuing Query 1");
        System.out.println(hQuery.toString());
        SearchResponse searchResponse1 = client
                .prepareSearch("foo_oa_hr_askforleave")
                .setQuery(hQuery).execute().actionGet();

        System.out.println("There were " + searchResponse1.getHits().getTotalHits()
                         + " results found for Query 1.");
        System.out.println(searchResponse1.toString());
        System.out.println();
```